# Customize existing document and add new fields in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two document with following structure

```
{
"CollegeName" : "Hi-Tech College",
"StudentName" : "John",
"Age" : 25
},
{
"CollegeName" : "Hi-Tech College",
"StudentName" : "Tom",
"Age" : 24
}
```

In those two document collegename is the common fields, by using that I want generate following format of a single document

```
{
"CollegeName" : "Hi-Tech College",
"JohnAge" : 25,
"TomAge" : 24
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            CollegeName: { $first: "$CollegeName" },
            Students: { $push: { k: { $concat: [ "$StudentName", "Age" ] }, v: "$Age" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { CollegeName: "$CollegeName" }, { $arrayToObject: "$Students" } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically to create key names dynamically you can use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator which takes an array of key-value pairs (`k` and `v` properties) and returns an object. To create your custom keys you can use [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html). Then you have to "merge" new dynamically created object with `CollegeName` so you can use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) operators for that.

Since it's grouping by `null` which returns one document for entire collection you have to keep in mind that MongoDB has BSON document size limit, so your result can't exceed 16MB. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.temp.aggregate([
{"$group":{"_id":{"CollegeName":"$CollegeName"},
"Students":{"$push":{"StudentName":"$StudentName","Age":"$Age"}}}}
,{"$unwind":"$Students"}
,,{"$group":{"_id":"$_id",
  'JohnAge': { $max: {$cond: [ {$or: [
        {$eq:['$Students.StudentName', 'John']}
        ]}
        , '$Students.Age', null] } },
   'TomAge': { $max: {$cond: [ {$or: [
        {$eq:['$Students.StudentName', 'Tom']}
        ]}
        , '$Students.Age', null] } }
    }}
])
```